# Scroll with limited list items - no jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a list of some arbitrary amount of items > 10, but I'm trying to use just 10 actual list item elements. I would like this to still be scrollable, but never render more than 10 list items, I'm not sure if I would have to reuse each list item and change the text of all 10, giving it the appearance of scrolling or something similar.

My reasoning behind this is the data I have comes in quickly and I don't want to add thousands of list items to the DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like what your'e describing is often referred to as infinite scroll. I'm more of a fan of pagination, as it's significantly easier to implement. Are you hard set on the infinite scrolling behavior? If you are, one of the things you can do is listen to the a scroll event and calculate if it needs to fetch more data (that's the most common technique)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen techniques similar to that, the issue from what I've seen is that with all those methods they are adding more list items instead of modifying pre-existing elements.

Comment: They are, I don't think there'd be much difference performance wise between adding a new element to the DOM and removing an old one, vs keeping only 10 elements and continually editing the `innerHTML` or something of a bunch of `li`'s-- since both would kick off a re-render

Comment: You're right, regardless it will cause a repaint I'm pretty sure. The issue I face is that if the program is left open for more than a few minutes, there will be thousands of list items now and could potentially crash the browser which is why the repaints from scrolling would be a better solution than allowing the list to constantly grow.

Comment: Gotya. What about removing DOM nodes as well as you're adding new ones?

Comment: I'm currently doing that actually once the list hits its limit. Maybe I need to look into adding more elements based on cached data when it's scrolled to the limit

Comment: If that's getting a little expensive, you could also do it in chunks, aka add/remove `li`'s batches at a time so that you're not always re-rendering. Kinda like using a throttle or debounce function which are pretty common, just so your browser isn't going crazy

Comment: I don't understand the scrollability. If there are only 10 elements it seems unnecessary or at least not affecting the way of solving the problem. If you want to be able to scroll in history, that would be a bit complicated but doable. Each chat works like that. You could stay scrolled to the end, removing older items and adding newer one by one in some interval. Once the user scrolls up you will have to stop the removing and instead start reverse infinite scroll and load older items via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrollable div (**widget-view**) with two children: a list (**widget-list**) with only 10 items and a transparent div (**widget-surface**) above it. The important thing is to keep the height of **widget-surface** equal to the height of an imaginary list with all the items. Then in the onscroll event of **widget-view**, you can find out which items would be visible, and update **widget-list**.

In the following example, you can change the height of **widget-view** and the line-height of **widget-list** to set the number of items in **widget-list**, e.g. you can have 10 items with the following values:

```css
.widget-list
{
    line-height: 20px ;
}
.widget-view
{
    height: 200px ; /* A multiple of widget-list's line-height */
}
```

And the only function you should change is:

```
function updateList( list, from, to )
```

Where **list** is the ul node, **from** is the first visible item index and **to-1** is the last visible item index. updateList is called when the list is "scrolled" or is modified. The example shows the index of the visible items.

Each **widget** is defined as follows:

```html
<div class="widget" id="widget-1">
    <div class="widget-view">
        <div class="widget-surface">
        </div>
        <ul class="widget-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addFive('widget-1');">Add 5</button><!--
    --><button onclick="delFive('widget-1');">Del 5</button>
    <p class="widget-label"></p>
</div>
```

And initialized in the onload event of window as follows:

```js
initializeWidget( "widget-1", 20 ) ; /* 20 initial items */
```

I added two buttons on each **widget** to add and delete 5 items respectively.

**Here is the working example**:

```js
addEventListener( "load", onWindowLoad, false ) ;
function updateList( list, from, to )
{
    var i, c = list.childNodes ;
    for( i = 0 ; i < c.length ; ++i )
    {
        if( c[i].tagName === "LI" )
        {
            c[i].innerHTML = from < to ? "Item " + from++ : "" ;
        }
    }
}
function onWindowLoad( )
{
    initializeWidget( "widget-1", 10 ) ;
    initializeWidget( "widget-2", 3 ) ;
    initializeWidget( "widget-3", 5 ) ;
}
function getComputed( element, property )
{
    if( element.currentStyle )
    {
        return element.currentStyle[property] ;
    }
    else
    {
        return window.getComputedStyle(element,null)[property] ;
    }
}
function getComputedPX( element, property )
{
    var b = getComputed( element, property ) ;
    return b ? parseInt( b.replace("px",""), 10 ) : b ;
}
function hasClass( node, cname )
{
    if( !node.className ) return false ;
    var i, l = node.className.split(' ') ;
    for( i = 0 ; i < l.length ; ++i )
    {
        if( l[i] === cname ) return true ;
    }
    return false ;
}
function getFirstChildByClass( parent, cname )
{
    if( !parent ) return null ;
    var i, l = parent.childNodes ;
    for( i = 0 ; i < l.length ; ++i )
    {
        if( this.hasClass( l[i], cname ) ) return l[i] ;
    }
    return null ;
}
function getView( widget )
{
    return getFirstChildByClass( widget, "widget-view" ) ;
}
function getLabel( widget )
{
    return getFirstChildByClass( widget, "widget-label" ) ;
}
function getSurface( widget )
{
    var view = getView( widget ) ;
    return getFirstChildByClass( view, "widget-surface" ) ;
}
function getList( widget )
{
    var view = getView( widget ) ;
    return getFirstChildByClass( view, "widget-list" ) ;
}
function getLineHeight( widget )
{
    var list = getList( widget ) ;
    return getComputedPX( list, "lineHeight" ) ;
}
function getHeight( widget )
{
    var surface = getSurface( widget ) ;
    return getComputedPX( surface, "height" ) ;
}
function getViewHeight( widget )
{
    var view = getView( widget ) ;
    return getComputedPX( view, "height" ) ;
}
function addItems( widget, number )
{
    var lineHeight = getLineHeight( widget ) ;
    var height = getHeight( widget ) ;
    var newHeight = height + lineHeight * number ;
    var surface = getSurface( widget ) ;
    if( newHeight < 0 ) newHeight = 0 ;
    surface.style.height = newHeight + "px" ;
    updateWidgetPosition( widget ) ;
    var label = getLabel( widget ) ;
    label.innerHTML = "<b>Loaded</b>: " + (newHeight/lineHeight) + " items" ;
}
function addFive( id )
{
    var widget = document.getElementById( id ) ;
    addItems( widget, 5 ) ;
}
function delFive( id )
{
    var widget = document.getElementById( id ) ;
    addItems( widget, -5 ) ;
}
function updateWidgetPosition( widget )
{
    var lineHeight = getLineHeight( widget ) ;
    var height = getHeight( widget ) ;
    var view = getView( widget ) ;
    var from = Math.round( view.scrollTop / lineHeight ) ;
    var to = from + height / lineHeight ;
    var list = getList( widget ) ;
    updateList( list, from, to ) ;
}
function onScroll( )
{
    updateWidgetPosition( this.parentNode ) ;
}
function initializeWidget( id, number )
{
    var widget = document.getElementById( id ) ;
    var view = getView( widget ) ;
    view.addEventListener( "scroll", onScroll, false ) ;
    var list = getList( widget ) ;
    var lineHeight = getLineHeight( widget ) ;
    var height = getViewHeight( widget ) ;
    var i, to = height / lineHeight ;
    for( i = 0 ; i < to ; ++i )
    {
        var li = document.createElement('LI');
        list.appendChild(li) ;
    }
    addItems( widget, number ) ;
}
```

```css
.widget-list
{
    line-height: 20px ;
}
.widget-view
{
    height: 100px ; /* A multiple of widget-list's line-height */
}
.widget
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;
    overflow: hidden ;
    width: 30% ;

}
.widget-view
{
    overflow: hidden ;
    overflow-y: scroll ;
    border: 1px solid #888 ;
}
.widget-list
{
    position: absolute ; 
    top: 0 ;
    left: 0 ;
    z-index: -1 ;
    margin: 0 ;
    width: 100% ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;
    list-style-type: none ;
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px ;
}
.widget button
{
    width: 50% ;
    font-size: 14pt ; 
}
body
{
    font-family: sans-serif ; 
    color: #555 ;

}
```

```html
<div class="widget" id="widget-1">
    <div class="widget-view">
        <div class="widget-surface">
        </div>
        <ul class="widget-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addFive('widget-1');">Add 5</button><!--
    --><button onclick="delFive('widget-1');">Del 5</button>
    <p class="widget-label"></p>
</div>
<div class="widget" id="widget-2">
    <div class="widget-view">
        <div class="widget-surface">
        </div>
        <ul class="widget-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addFive('widget-2');">Add 5</button><!--
    --><button onclick="delFive('widget-2');">Del 5</button>
    <p class="widget-label"></p>
</div>
<div class="widget" id="widget-3">
    <div class="widget-view">
        <div class="widget-surface">
        </div>
        <ul class="widget-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addFive('widget-3');">Add 5</button><!--
    --><button onclick="delFive('widget-3');">Del 5</button>
    <p class="widget-label"></p>
</div>
```

I hope you can adapt it to your needs.